# IntStream.sum() exception handling

Tags: java, java-8

Why does `IntStream.sum()` return an int value? Is it some conceptual mistake? When creating a stream from the exemplary array:

```
int A[] = {2^31-5, 2, 2, 2};
```

Sum of all elements exceeds the maximal integer value, but no exception is thrown. Does anybody know how to prevent such situations?

Comment: Why would an exception be thrown? If you need a `long` you will have to [convert to a `LongStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asLongStream--).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior matches what you get when summing up `int`s in a loop. There are various ways to deal with overflow, all of them being a trade-off between general applicability and performance and since it isn’t obvious which one the API will/should use, the one which is commonly known by Java developers has been chosen.

If you want to sum using a bigger data type, you can use either

```
long sumL=IntStream.of(A).asLongStream().sum();// may still overflow
```

or

```
BigInteger sum = IntStream.of(A).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                          .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);// might be slower
```

If you want throwing behavior, you can use

```
int sum=IntStream.of(A).reduce(0, (a,b)->{
    int c=a+b;
    if(a>0? b>0 && c<0: b<0&& c>0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("overflow");
    return c;
});
```

or, much simpler (integrating Stuart Marks’ solution)

```
int sum=IntStream.of(A).reduce(0, Math::addExact);
```

Comment: @Boris the Spider: How could I forget about that… Thanks

Answer (score 9):

By default, integral arithmetic in Java does not throw any exception if overflow occurs. Operations that overflow are truncated to the low order 32 bits for `int` and 64 bits for `long`.

If you want an exception to be thrown for overflow conditions, you can use the "exact" family of functions in the [`java.lang.Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class:

- `addExact`
- `decrementExact`
- `incrementExact`
- `multiplyExact`
- `negateExact`
- `subtractExact`
- `toIntExact`

These are defined to be the same as ordinary arithmetic operations on `int` and `long` except that they throw `ArithmeticException` on overflow instead of truncating the result.

Using streams, your example would look like this:

```
int a[] = { Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5, 2, 2, 2 };
int sum = Arrays.stream(a).reduce(0, Math::addExact);
```

This will throw `ArithmeticException`.

(Note that your example as written uses `2^31-5` which is a valid expression as `^` is the XOR operator. The result is 24 which of course will not give an overflow.)

Comment: I felt that there is (has to be) such a method but I searched `java.lang.Integer`, as I knew it has the `sum` method, for an alternative sum method and didn’t thought about `java.lang.Math`. That’s why I wrote a manual check as lambda expression. Is there a pattern behind the decision for the class location and method name that would help me to find such methods in the future?

Comment: @Holger Yeah I knew these functions had been added and the first place I looked was `java.lang.Integer`. I was a little surprised to find them in `java.lang.Math`. To a certain extent it's a matter of judgment where such operations go. There were already a lot of primitive operations in `Math` such as `abs()`, `max()`, transcendentals, `round()`, `signum()`, etc., some with overloads for different primitives, so it does seem reasonable to have put the "exact" operations int `Math` as well.